# show error with the following python codes

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

show error with the following python codes

Error:

```
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Python Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://datatables.net/")
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').text
```

Expected Result :

```
Airi Satou
```

Comment: just print without `.text` attribute to see what it's like, then decide

Comment: dear @Jean-FrançoisFabre , fixed, i guess element and elements difference, i am so stupid !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns *list* of WebElements while you need to extract text from *single* WebElement.

Either try

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').text
```

or

```
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')[0].text
```